# Laravel dynamic queries with premade string

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

How to insert strings as query in Laravel? I have to handle a dynamic value for "book formats" (such as "pdf", "epub", "physical", "") and this formats are separated by comma. Here is my code:

```
$formats_sql = '';
$format_filter_count = 0;
$format_filter = explode(',', $format_filter);
foreach ($format_filter as $format_filter_tmp) {
    if ($format_filter_count == 0) {
        $formats_sql .= "where('format', '=', '{$format_filter_tmp}')";
    } else {
        $formats_sql .= "->orWhere('format', '=', '{$format_filter_tmp}')";
    }
    $format_filter_count += 1;
}

if ($price_filter == 'paid') {
    $books = Book::where('book_id', '=', $category_book->book_id)->$formats_sql->where('sell_price', '>', '0')->where('status', '=', '1')->get();
}
```

But makes this problem:

```
Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder::$where('format', '=', 'pdf')->orWhere('format', '=', 'epub')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your over complicating this. You should be using `whereIn` where you need to search for an array of values.

You whole code above can be condensed to:

```
if ($price_filter == 'paid') {
    $formats = explode(',', $format_filter);
    Book::where('book_id', $category_book->book_id)->whereIn('format', $formats)->where('sell_price', '>', '0')->where('status', '1')->get();
}
```